# Useradd script in linux without using passwd

Tags: linux, bash, passwords

I have to write a *useradd script* which adds a new user and sets for him a home directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Name:"
read name
echo "Password:"
read password
echo "Group:"
read group
useradd -m -G $group -s /bin/bash -p $password $name
```

Everything works as intended but I have problems with the password in the following line -

> `useradd -m -G $group -s /bin/bash -p $password $name`

It does not work so I need to use later in terminal `passwd` command.

How can I rebuild my script so I won't need to use `passwd` to setup password correctly? I have read that you can use stdin but I was not able to do this correctly.

Comment: The method you're trying to use it expects the encrypted password as an argument. From man page `-p` is `The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3)`. You can use the `chpasswd` which updates passwords in batch mode.

Comment: And how can i add this to my code? I tried using ' echo "password:name" | chpasswd' instead of echo "Password" and i tried to do same line of code in the end but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to pipe the user's password from *STDIN*, use `chpasswd` utility which is quick and simple.
as suggested by [@Ardit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297135/ardit).

This script should work for your purpose, assuming you meet the following conditions-

- You are interacting as the **root user**
- You have an existing group created for the purpose of your new user

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Name:"
read name

echo "Password:"
read password

echo "Group:"   # group must exist
read group

# add new user, set group, create new home directory 
useradd -G $group -m $name           

# update new user password by piping from STDIN
echo ""$name":"$password"" | chpasswd           

# change the default user shell to bash 
chsh -s /bin/bash $name
```

1. First we execute `useradd` command to **create** the new user and **assign** it to an existing group.
2. Then we **pipe** the name and password into `chpasswd`. If you're wondering why wrap those variable expansions with double quotes, [check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104627/8568965) .
3. Finally `chsh` utility is used to update the user shell.

> **Why not execute everything in a single statement?**
>
>  I prefer subdividing a problem into smaller tasks for easier understanding.

Comment: Tkank You very much it works as intended, and thanks for detailed explanation.